# css trying to resize jQuery datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datepicker

I need to resize this datepicker... But the calendar part just doesn't want to resize with the datepicker...

Image:

[image: datepicker]

Code(CSS):

```
.ui-datepicker-inline {
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 540px) {
    #headerSeparator {
        width: 80%;
    }
    .ui-datepicker-inline, .ui-datepicker, .ui-datepicker-calendar, .ui-widget-content {
        width: 80%;
    }
}
```

**Edit**:

here is my javascript

```
$(document).ready(function()
                    {
                        $("#datepicker").datepicker({ dayNamesMin: ["DIM", "LYN", "MAR", "MER", "JEU", "VEN", "SAM"], monthNames: ["Janvier", "Février", "Mars", "Avril", "Mai", "Juin", "Juillet", "Août", "Septembre", "Octobre", "Novembre", "Décembre"], altField: "#date", dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd" });
                    });
```

Comment: Can you please add this in jsfiddle?

Comment: Can you make a fiddle / post the html and rest of the css? Much harder to fix the problem without the code!

Comment: I think you can overcome the default by using !important but please post your code so we can see the issue

Comment: It's because the actual dates are in a table which will always have a minimum width to show the contents inside it, in your case the days.  You either need to add overflow:auto to datapicker div or make the font size smaller on the table so it allows the table to go smaller

Comment: I can see the cell padding is high may be reducing that will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better to change the font size of date picker rather than width.Just try this code:

```
.ui-datepicker{
 font-size:13px;
}
```

Comment: The text just gets too small

Comment: try with 15px or some other value as you need.